# Azure Data Factory: Difference Between Two Row Values

Tags: azure-data-factory

Looking for a way in Azure Data Factory to get the difference of the same column from the latest record to next-latest record.

For example, how to create the "Difference" column here:

ID Value Difference
04 230 25
03 205 0
02 205 5
01 200

Comment: What format are the source files / source data?  Where are they?  eg datalake, database etc

Comment: The source files are parquet files in a data lake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Window transformation to do this. Please follow the step:

1.Add source.

[image]

2. Add a Window transformation and set like the following screenshot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Data preview:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use the serverless SQL pools service in Azure Synapse Analytics.  This is a pay-as-you-go service which allows you to query flat files, json and parquet stored on your Azure storage

Here's a sample query against a .csv file, but could just as easily be parquet:

```
SELECT
    [id],
    [value],
    [value] - LAG([value]) OVER( ORDER BY [id] ) diff
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://someLake.dfs.core.windows.net/datalake/raw/csv/diff.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        HEADER_ROW = TRUE
    ) AS [result]
ORDER BY [id] DESC
```

My results:

[image: Results]

You could then use this SQL statement as a source for a Copy activity in Azure Data Factory for example.